# issue accessing /dev/mem and /dev/kmem

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I am having Android 2.3.7 (Cyanogen mod), the 2 nodes /dev/mem and /dev/kmem do not exist on my device.
I have tried the following two commands to create the nodes:

```
# mknod /dev/mem c 1 1
# chown root.mem /dev/mem

# mknod /dev/kmem c 1 2
# chown root.kmem /dev/kmem
```

but I get the error: `chown: unknown user/group root:mem`

It seems like I can create the nodes, but I cannot bind them with the mem and kmem.
Please give me some suggestion.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably seeing several separate issues:

1. The Android installation that you are using has no existing user groups `mem` and `kmem` for controlling access to those devices. Just use an existing group instead...
2. `/dev/kmem` could very well be [disabled](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/DEVKMEM.html) - creating the device node would do nothing in that case.
3. I would expect `/dev/mem` to be *at least* [filtered](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/STRICT_DEVMEM.html), if not outright disabled through some patch.

Why do you need to use either of these virtual devices?